# How to trigger on Hover over Border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I want to react if a user hovers over a border (or into its near).

I got an table for ERD / UML diagrams and I want to give the user the opportunity to resize this table by dragging the tables border. I am working with jQuery and pure JS. My tables are rectangles and its positions are known (x1, x2, y1, y2, width , height , (x1 | y1 ) is top-left, (x2 | y2) is bottom-right ).  Every table has the class "diagram" , so I thought about triggering the ."diagram".hover and check the mouse position, but this would be non performant.

I am mainly searching for idears, but short examples would be great.

Code update:
http://codepad.org/3xr8H39m

Comment: Post what you have tried so far

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in a wrapper and prevent event happening in its children. See below:

```js
var border = document.getElementById("border");

border.onmouseover = function(e) {
  if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
  console.log("border-hover")
}
```

```css
#border {
  padding: 4px;
  background: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div id="border">
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want to do this on table columns ?

Comment: @Fathy, wrap the table contents in two `div`'s, an outer and an inner. Add the border to the outer and away you go. If needing more help, feel free to create a new question and add a link here :)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is no special method to catch hovering over borders, so you will need some workaround. The first way is to create external container wrapped around the table, with some pixels padding, so you will have some border, and detect hovering over both external container and the inner table, like here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var innerHover = false;
        $('.inner_table')
            .on('mouseover', function() {
                innerHover = true;
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
                innerHover = false;
            });
       // check if we can start resizing
       $('.external_wrapper').on('click', function() {
           if (!innerHover) {
               // we can start resizing!
           }
       });
   });
</script>

<div class="external_wrapper" style="padding: 3px;">
    <table class="inner_table">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

The other way is to create thin additional `div`s along all four table borders and use them as click anchors. This way is user in jQueryUI dialog widget. It is much more flexible as you will not be glued to container borders.